# Get the td with column-index > 3 and value > 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the `td` with the `column-index>3` and `value>6`, I've written the code to get the `td` with an `column-index>3`:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
            gtchild: function (elem) {
          var $elem = $(elem),
            $row = $elem.parent();
        return  $row.find("td").index($elem) > 3;
    }
});
```

I can get the `td` with the `value>6` like

```
return $row.find("td").text()>6
```

How do I combine them together?

Comment: formating the code to easily read several times ,but it do not work,sorry

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a good use case for selector expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine your 2 conditions :

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    gtchild: function (elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem),
            $row = $elem.parent();
        return $row.find("td").index($elem) > 3 && $elem.text() > 6;
    }
});
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/jjnUj/

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
$row.children().slice(3).filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) > 6;
});
```

If you've got more than one row, switch to `.find("td:nth-child(n+4)")`.